# ¿Cómo puedo hacer una lista dentro de otra lista y cómo llamarla?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

He intentado colocar de la siguiente manera:

```cpp
struct NodoPersona{
    string usuario, clave;
    struct NodoCartera *cartera;
    NodoPersona *siguiente;
}

struct NodoCartera{
    string direccion, moneda;
    double saldo;
    NodoCartera *siguiente;
}
```

Quisiera saber cómo llamar la variable de NodoCartera en NodoPersona y si la forma cómo la estoy haciendo, está bien o está mala.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este es un peque~no ejemplo.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


struct NodoPersona{
    string usuario, clave;
    struct NodoCartera *cartera;
    NodoPersona *siguiente;
};

struct NodoCartera{
    string direccion, moneda;
    double saldo;
    NodoCartera *siguiente;
};

int main() {
  NodoPersona * personas = new NodoPersona();
  personas->usuario = "User";
  personas->clave = "******";
  personas->cartera = NULL;

  NodoPersona * persona1 =  new  NodoPersona();
  personas->siguiente = persona1;

  persona1->usuario = "User1";
  persona1->clave = "*******";
  NodoCartera * cartera =  new NodoCartera();
  persona1->cartera  = cartera;

  cartera->direccion = "Dir";
  // ..... 
   NodoPersona * personaCursor = personas;
  while (personaCursor !=NULL) {
      std::cout << "usuario:" << personaCursor->usuario << endl;
      NodoCartera * carteraCursor = personaCursor->cartera;
      while (carteraCursor != NULL) {
        std::cout << " direccion:" << carteraCursor->direccion << endl;
        carteraCursor = carteraCursor->siguiente;

      }

      personaCursor = personaCursor->siguiente;

  }

}
```

Comment: Una pregunta. debería crearse la información primero en *cartera para guardarla en persona1->cartera, ¿no?

Comment: Solo hace falta crear el puntero y asociarlo a persona1->cartera. El resto de los datos se pueden llenar después. Pero lo más acertado es tener métodos que creen las estructuras con los datos adecuados y luego enlazarlos.

Comment: ¡Gracias!. Lo pude implementar en el proyecto y funcionó, ahora a programar como si no existiera un mañana